# Name of first column that is non NaN ir Null

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking how to add a column to df that holds the column name of the first column that is not NaN or Null. Example: column "first" based on columns 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'

> 

```
Name    A     B   C   D   First

Alex    100  Nan Null NaN   A

Michael 300  400 Null Null  A

Steve   Null 100 100  100   B

John    Null Null Nan Null Null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `Null, Nan` values to misisng values and if necessary `Name` to index, then test [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and get first matched column by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), last set `NaN` if all `NaN`s per row:

```
df = df.replace(['Null', 'Nan'], np.nan)
df = df.set_index('Name')

m = df.notna()
df['First'] = m.idxmax(axis=1).where(m.any(axis=1))
print (df)
           A    B    C    D First
Name                             
Alex     100  Nan  NaN  NaN     A
Michael  300  400  NaN  NaN     A
Steve    NaN  100  100  100     B
John     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

If need original values without replace:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
m = df.isin(['Null', 'Nan']) | df.isna()

df['First'] = (~m).idxmax(axis=1).mask(m.all(axis=1), 'Null')
```